# Maximizing choice

Tags: regression, machine-learning, probability

There are N number of people and X amount of objects with different values. Each person will choose an object and will obtain that object's value. If multiple people choose the same object then the value of the object is shared among the people. For example, If there are 2 objects and 3 people, one of the objects will be chosen by at least 2 people; thus the value of the object is divided by 2.  Each round people make their decisions with new objects and new values. How can a person maximize their expected values accumulated from their choices in Q number of rounds? (Q belongs to $[1,~+\infty)$.)

Learning other players' decisions and their accumulated values can help in future decision making.